# add grid when landscape bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to know is there any way to add grid when using lanscape for mobile phone. im using bootstrap v3

heres my code

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="card m-15">
    <div class="card-top">
      <img src="img/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="card-caption">
      <h6 class="text-center uppercase bold">chocolate chip cookies</h6>
      <p>by <a href="#">lipsum</a>
      </p>
      <div class="tag">
        <a href="#">lipsum</a>,<a href="#"> lipsum</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="card m-15">
    <div class="card-top">
      <img src="img/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="card-caption">
      <h6 class="text-center uppercase bold">chocolate chip cookies</h6>
      <p>by <a href="#">lipsum</a>
      </p>
      <div class="tag">
        <a href="#">lipsum</a>,<a href="#"> lipsum</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

for the result in media xs in potraint mode its fine. but when in landscape mode it taking to big space.

can i change from col-xs-12 to col-xs-6 when i only use in landscape mode?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, I think the easiest way to achieve this will be through the use of media queries. Using a media query in CSS you can detect when the width of the window has changed and adjust properties accordingly. Without using javascript there is no way to add or remove a class so we can't change col-xs-12 to col-xs-6

The first change I would make is adding a row class to your divs:

> < div class="row col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> content < /div >

Then we will use a media query to see when the width of the screen has been changed (this will be in an external CSS file).

```
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .row {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 20%;
  }
}
```

This says that when our window is at least 400px wide we will give the row div a width of 60% and give it a margin-left of 20% so that is is centered.

[Here is an example I made](https://jsfiddle.net/JackBid/4b99yu5k/)